# Glue joint bit, recommended?

Tags: joinery

I was wondering if I should get a [glue joint router bit](http://www.precisionbits.com/reversible-finger-joint-glue-joint-router-bit-1-2-shank-yonico-15131.html) to make the glue joints. It would make it stay in place better and stronger right? What would you all think about that? All input is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `I was wondering if I should get a glue joint router bit to make the glue joints.`  Not entirely sure what you mean by that.  Are you talking about [one of these](http://www.thewoodwhisperer.com/articles/does-a-glue-line-bit-add-strength-to-a-joint/)?

Comment: http://www.precisionbits.com/reversible-finger-joint-glue-joint-router-bit-1-2-shank-yonico-15131.html

Comment: Sorry for not showing the bit, I am referring to something like this for joinery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if I should get a glue joint router bit to make the glue joints. It would make it stay in place better and stronger right?

Glue joints, when properly prepared, are at least as strong as the wood material that they are bonding.  Even a simple panel joint (two boards glued to each other along the long grain) is very strong at the joint.

Adding the "fingers" that this type of router bit does nothing to increase the strength of a long-grain glue joint.  These types of router bits are useful when joining end grain, like you see in a lot of manufactured furniture (IKEA, for example).

[image: finger joint]
<sup>([source](http://my.woodmagazine.com/woodworking-tips/techniques/joinery/end-to-end/))</sup>

For end grain, the fingers supply much-needed long-grain-to-long-grain glue surface, which is *much* stronger than an end-grain-to-end-grain butt joint.

> It would make it stay in place better

You are correct, this type of router bit would help align the two boards for gluing (assuming you set everything up correctly when using the router bit).

**Bottom line, unless you're joining end grain to end grain, you don't need one.**

Comment: I understand what it is used for now. And knowing that I could glue end-grain to end-grain really helps me, thank you!

Comment: @leonardkritzjr, thanks for accepting my answer.  However, it's usually a good idea to leave things unanswered for at least a few hours to give others a chance.  Someone might have a another point of view or even a better answer but will not add it because you've already accepted one.